# A property of Loewner ordering

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A$ is a $m \times n$ ($m>n$) semi-orthogonal matrix such that $A^TA=I$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements. Let us define

$$T(a) = (A^TDPA)(A^TPDPA)^{-1}(A^TDPA)$$

where $P = (D+aI)^{-1}$ and $a>0$.
Equivalently, $$T(a) = (A^TD(D+aI)^{-1}A)(A^T(D+aI)^{-1}D(D+aI)^{-1}A)^{-1}(A^TD(D+aI)^{-1}A)$$
$T(a)$ is a positive definite matrix and I want to show that

if $a>b$ then $T(a) > T(b)$ with the meaning that $T(a)-T(b)$ is a positive definite matrix.

In other words, note $P$ is a positive definite matrix and the question can be "is $T(P)$ a monotonic decreasing function of $P$, $P>Q$ then $T(P)<T(Q)$?".

Comment: Minor point: in the last sentence I think you mean increasing; otherwise there is a conflict with the preceding sentence.

Comment: a and b are scalers while P and Q are matrices. When a>b  then P(a) < P(b) then T(P(a)) > T(P(b)).